# Make a struct have non-padded size

Tags: c, binary

So, I want to be able to write binary data in C that alternates between a single byte and a 32-bit signed integer, and have a struct type that can be used for this with pointer incrementing.

So far, this is my struct

```
struct MarkedInt
{
  unsigned char mark;
  int value;
};
```

And this is my code

```
void clean_obj(struct MarkedInt* mi)
{
  mi->mark = 0;
  mi->value = 0;
}

int main(void) {

  struct MarkedInt a;
  clean_obj(&a);
  a.mark = 5;
  a.value = 500;

  unsigned char* printer = (unsigned char*)(&a);
  printf("sizeof a is %lu\n", sizeof(a));
  for(int i = 0; i< sizeof(a);i++)
  {
    printf("%u\n", printer[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, the result of the program is this

```
sizeof a is 8
5
4
64
0
244
1
0
0
```

So it sets the size of my struct `MarkedInt` at 8, making the mark member 4 bytes instead of 1. This causes some unwanted padding, where a pointer to the struct used to read binary data would be reading 8 bytes at a time and not 5.

My desired outcome is this

```
unsigned char buf[] = {/*mark*/ 5, /*int value*/ 1, 0, 0, 0};
struct MarkedInt* reader = buf;
printf(" mark: %u, value: %d\n", reader->mark, reader->value);
```

Is it possible to do this in c? Or is simply reading the byte marker and int separately recommended?

Comment: You asked, is it possible to do in *C*, and the answer is "it is not possible to do it in C, but it might be possible to do with some extensions" and yes, the *preferable way* is to read separately.